# How to change the precision of a float conversion?

Tags: java

I am trying to convert float value to 32 bit unsigned long value and facing the problem of loss of value.
`long v = (long) f;`

Here when `f` is 4294967295 ((2^32) -1). The conversion to long returns 4294967296 instead of 4294967295 because float conversion is precised to 7 decimal places. I need precision to  9 decimal places. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Can you use a `double` instead?

Comment: You can try using `BigDecimal`, it has al the precision you'll ever need

Comment: As you describe it, the problem is not with casting your float to a long, but with using a float at all.

Comment: "float conversion is precised to 7 decimal places" depends how big your float is.

Comment: `float` should never be used for precise values, it's a known fact.

Comment: 'float` *itself* is only precise to 7 decimal *integral digits,* never mind 'conversion'. There is no such thing as 'unsigned long' or '32-bit unsigned long' in Java. Longs are signed and 64-bit. Unclear what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

Quote from Java Puzzlers: Traps, Pitfalls, and Corner Cases book:

> Floating-point operations return the floating-point value that is closest to their
>   exact mathematical result. Once the distance between adjacent floating-point values
>   is greater than 2, adding 1 to a floating-point value will have no effect,
>   because the half-way point between values won’t be reached. For the float type,
>   the least magnitude beyond which adding 1 will have no effect is 2^25, or
>   33,554,432; for the double type, it is 2^54, or approximately 1.8 × 10^16.

So basicly, if you want to represent big numbers, `float` is a bad idea. Above 2^25 it is not able to represent at least every other integer. It get worse the bigger the number gets.

The best option for you would be to use `BigDecimal` instead.